# Custom Raspberry Pi hostname to run Flask app

Tags: hostname

I want to run a Python Flask app with a Raspberry Pi. The pi is connected through a router. Thus the Flask web app can be viewed from other devices connected to the router. However, my raspberry pi IP address is 192.168.1.145 and the app runs with this URL 192.168.1.145:5000. I would give a meaningful hostname to the raspberry pi like flaskserver:5000 and make it accessible to other devices connected to the same router as pi.

I have tried the following steps-

1. In flask app my code is
   `app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'flaskserver:5000' app.run(host = '192.168.1.145', port = 5000, debug=True, use_reloader=False)`
2. I have added this line to my /etc/hosts
   192.168.1.145. flaskserver
   That did not work. So I tried -
   127.0.0.1 flaskserver
3. I have also tried the following code for my flask server -
   `app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'flaskserver:5000' app.run(host = 'flaskserver', port = 5000, debug=True, use_reloader=False)`

I am making a lot of trial and error with the configurations. So far nothing has worked.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a reverse proxy such as nginx to expose your application to port 80. Then change the host file to whatever you want.